# Finding a string in a list using in

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a program about players and scores and the program basically stores the names and scores of the players (added by the user) and one of the requirement is finding players by their name. Names and scores are added to a list name playerList

```
def findgolfer():
    playerList.sort()
         while True:
             findd=input("Enter a golfer's name\n(m for main menu)\n")

for findd in playerList:
    print (findd, "score =", playerList[playerList.index(findd)]

if findd == 'm':
  print (findd, " does not exist")
main()
```

When the code is executed all the players in the list are displayed and not just the player and their score the user want. My question being how do I get the program to only display the name and the score of the player that I want?

Comment: Your code is unclear. Your while runs forever, your are doing nothing with the result of the input, and it looks like that `if` should be in the while after the input and redirect to some menu (and not print does not exist.). Finding if an element is in a list is simple as `if findd in playerList:` - this is basic Python stuff.

Comment: im sorry but i did add if instead of for but then it says 'does not exist' it doesnt even display everyone

Comment: This is an [XY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) problem. What are you trying to do in this piece of code and what you are asking are probably not the same. Are you trying to get user input and add it to a list until something happens, then look at the list? Clarify this to yourself, then if you don't know how to proceed edit your question with a concise goal - what do you want to achieve? -and the problem you have.

Comment: There are mainly 4 parts of the code the first one of them being adding names and scores of players to a list named playerList and then this is the second part (the second function) which should retrieve the player name that the user inputs with his score if he is already entered as a player in the list. @kabanus sorry that this is all unclear but I hope i made my question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on your question writing. Specifically what you wrote in the comment should be clear in the question. Your questions is:

**Given a list of of pairs (player,score), and a player name (string), how do I check if the player exists and retrieve the score if she does?**

If you wrote something like that, it would be clear that you're method of keeping player scores is not the preferred one. I'll come back to this in a second. The simplest way, with only a bit of Python magic to do what you want:

```
#Assume inputPlayer was accepted as input
for player,score in playerList:
     if player == inputPlayer:
          print("Player",player,"has",score,"points.")
          break
else: print("Player",inputPlayer,"does not exist!")
```

This demonstrates the `for else` construct in Python you should read about. There are other ways to do this but it's worth knowing, as this is a special feature.

What is the "better" way? If you maintained your player and score list in a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict), you would have O(1) action and better readability (in my opinion). You can transfer the list of tuples to a `dict` easily with:

```
scores = dict(playerList)
```

but you probably want to build the `dict` in your initial code. Probably where you have a `playerList.append((user,score))` you will have a `scores[player] = score`. If that's the case then the above becomes:

```
try: print("Player",inputPlayer,"has",scores[inputPlayer],"points.")
except KeyError: print("Player",inputPlayer,"does not exist!")
```

Comment: And make sure your dict/list is populated properly before testing code!